# acf repeater was free in start

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a project. Where I need to update the plugins and WordPress version. while updating I saw acf and acf repeater separately. I have updated the acf plugin but couldn't find any update related to acf repeater. The acf repeater read.me file is showing version 1.1.1. When I include it in function.php the repeater field show repeater but didn't work on all site. Now my question is acf repeater was free in start so then the change it to pro version.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress.SE. Generally, plugins that are not part of the core WordPress package are considered off-topic by the wider community here. However, it seems you are in luck and have received an answer. If the answer has solved your problem consider accepting it (green tick). When you have a moment take the tour and check the help centre - that will help you get a lot more helpful answers down the road.

Comment: You should contact ACF support

Answer (score 2):

The ACF Repeater plugin as an additional component for the core ACF plugin was never free. The main difference is that before the ACF Pro version, those additional types of fields had to be purchased separately. Now they are all included in the ACF Pro version. [More info from the Docs.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/)

Comment: Thanks @dboris. How i can update acf-repeater. In plugins now update option is shown.Is there any way to update acf repeater or i need to purchase acf pro version ?

Comment: @majid Unfortunately yes, most of the premium plugins come with a yearly/monthly subscription plan. Though there are some open-source substitutions, but I haven't tested them: [https://github.com/wab/acf-repeater](https://github.com/wab/acf-repeater)